# Gorm always searches by ID, not by merchant_id

Tags: go, go-gorm

i have this struct

```
type MerchantCsvMapping struct {
    gorm.Model
    MerchantID       int 
    Name             string
    NameDe           string
    ProductNo        string
    PriceOld         string
    Ean              string
    Price            string
    Category         int
    DeepLink         string
    ShortDescription string
    LongDescription  string
    BrandMerchant    int
    MerchantImageURL string
    AlternateImage   string
    GalleryImage     int
    GalleryImage2    int
    GalleryImage3    int
    GalleryImage4    int
    DeliveryTime     string
    DeliveryCost     string
}
```

the table structure is

````
1   id  bigint unsigned NULL    NULL    NO  NULL    auto_increment      
2   merchant_id bigint unsigned NULL    NULL    NO  NULL        merchants(id)   
3   name    int unsigned    NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
4   product_no  int unsigned    NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
5   price_old   bigint unsigned NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
6   ean int unsigned    NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
7   price   bigint unsigned NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
8   category    int unsigned    NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
9   deep_link   int unsigned    NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
10  short_description   int unsigned    NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
11  long_description    int unsigned    NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
12  brand_merchant  int unsigned    NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
13  merchant_image_url  int unsigned    NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
14  alternate_image int unsigned    NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
15  gallery_image   bigint unsigned NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
16  gallery_image2  bigint unsigned NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
17  gallery_image3  bigint unsigned NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
18  gallery_image4  bigint unsigned NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
19  delivery_time   int unsigned    NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
20  delivery_cost   int unsigned    NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
21  created_at  timestamp   NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
22  updated_at  timestamp   NULL    NULL    YES NULL            
23  deleted_at  timestamp   NULL    NULL    YES NULL            ```
````

when i run this command with Feed.MerchantID = 1

```
db.First(&merchant_csv_mapping, Feed.MerchantID)
```

&merchant_csv is always merchant 29, as it has ID 1 and merchant_id 29

but i want to pick the entry for merchant with merchant_id = 1

it seems like gorm searches primarily for ID, not for merchant_id

i am now tackling this for hours :(

Maybe anyone of you has an idea

Regards
Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `First` only receives an integer. GORM will compare that to the primary key, unless you further specify the condition.

Use this instead:

```golang
db.First(&merchant_csv_mapping, "merchant_id = ?", Feed.MerchantID)
```

Comment: Thank you ! Important note: I had to remove the gorm.Model too